# page takes more time to load and display table records

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

I have created table display by using angularjs in codeigniter.I have mentioned below which i am using for displaying that table records.That table will have 200 records and each record will have 100 record inside that.so this code take much time to load page.

```
var chseble_app = angular.module('chseble_app', []);
chseble_app.controller('chsebale_ctlr', function($scope){
$scope.bale_list= <?= json_encode($bale_list); ?>;
$scope.total_wght = function(){
  var total_wght = 0;
  angular.forEach($scope.bale_list, function(lot){
    total_wght += parseFloat(lot.weight);    
  });
  return total_wght;
};
$scope.selected_lots = [];
$scope.selected_total = 0;
$scope.chk_lot = [];
$scope.chk_bale = [];
$scope.chk_all = false;
//checkbox checked function of lot row
$scope.lot_chkd = function(id){

    angular.forEach($scope.bale_list, function(lot){
      if(lot.id == id)
      {
        if(!$scope.chk_lot[id])
        {
          angular.forEach(lot.bales, function(bale){
            $scope.chk_bale[bale.id] = false;
          });
       }
      else
      {
          angular.forEach(lot.bales, function(bale){
            $scope.chk_bale[bale.id] = true;
          });
      }
      }
    });
  $scope.check_loop();      
}
```

//checkbox checked function of bale row

```
$scope.bale_chkd = function(bleid, lotid){
  $scope.check_loop();
}

//check/uncheck all checkboxes when select all check box is checked
$scope.check_all = function(){
  $scope.selected_total = 0;
  $scope.selected_lots = [];
  if($scope.chk_all)
  {
    angular.forEach($scope.bale_list, function(lot){
        $scope.selected_total += parseFloat(lot.weight);
        $scope.chk_lot[lot.id] = true;
        $scope.selected_lots.push(' '+lot.lot_no);
        angular.forEach(lot.bales, function(bale){$scope.chk_bale[bale.id] = true;});
    });
  }
  else
  {
    angular.forEach($scope.bale_list, function(lot){
        $scope.chk_lot[lot.id] = false;
        angular.forEach(lot.bales, function(bale){$scope.chk_bale[bale.id] = false;});
    });
  }
}

//calculate total and check or uncheck parent checkbox
$scope.check_loop = function(){
  $scope.selected_total = 0;
  $scope.selected_lots = [];
  var all_lot_chkd = true;
  angular.forEach($scope.bale_list, function(lot){
     var bale_chkd = false;
      angular.forEach(lot.bales, function(bale){
          if($scope.chk_bale[bale.id])
          {
            $scope.selected_total += parseFloat(bale.weight);
            $scope.chk_lot[lot.id] = true;
            bale_chkd = true;
          }
          else
          {
            all_lot_chkd = false;
          }
      });
    if(bale_chkd == false)
      $scope.chk_lot[lot.id] = false;
    else
      $scope.selected_lots.push(' '+lot.lot_no);
  });
      $scope.chk_all = all_lot_chkd;
}

});
```

I have tried settimeout method to load data after page load completed by below reference method,but not able to edit my code with that method code.Is there possible to change my code like that reference demo,or any other way is there to load faster that page?

[JSFiddle - Page load optimization](http://jsfiddle.net/wWcvx/1/)

```
 Array
    (
        [561] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 561
                [lot_no] => 1
                [weight] => 16230
                [staple] => 3600
                [mic] => 0
                [strength] => 0
                [trash] => 0
                [color_grade] => 0
                [bales] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 62941
                                [process_id] => 561
                                [press_no] => 1
                                [weight] => 162
                                [staple] => 36
                                [mic] => 0
                                [strength] => 0
                                [trash] => 0
                                [color_grade] => 0
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 62942
                                [process_id] => 561
                                [press_no] => 2
                                [weight] => 151
                                [staple] => 36
                                [mic] => 0
                                [strength] => 0
                                [trash] => 0
                                [color_grade] => 0
                            )
)
[562] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 562
            [lot_no] => 2
            [weight] => 15523
            [staple] => 3600
            [mic] => 0
            [strength] => 0
            [trash] => 0
            [color_grade] => 0
            [bales] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 63041
                            [process_id] => 562
                            [press_no] => 1
                            [weight] => 156
                            [staple] => 36
                            [mic] => 0
                            [strength] => 0
                            [trash] => 0
                            [color_grade] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 63042
                            [process_id] => 562
                            [press_no] => 2
                            [weight] => 148
                            [staple] => 36
                            [mic] => 0
                            [strength] => 0
                            [trash] => 0
                            [color_grade] => 0
                        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have each top-level record in an ng-repeat, you should have the container for its child data adorned with an ng-if to prevent the dom from rendering an excessive number of html elements. This means you will need to implement UI to expand the row in question (i.e. `ng-if="{{currentItem.expanded}}" ng-click={{currentItem.expanded == !currentItem.expanded}}`).

If you are binding properties in these child objects you may also want to look into one-way binding in which you prefix your bindings with a double-colon `{{::modelBeingOneWayBound}}`. This prevents your large dataset from spawning a ton of watchers which can hinder performance.

Both of the above suggestions would be implemented in the template. It will help others and I troubleshoot if you provide it.

Comment: I am not familiar in angularjs,so is there possible to mention where i can add this code in above mentioned my code?

Comment: As I previously mentioned, 'in the template'. If you do not know where it is, you may be able to search for it using the controller name; this is typically an html file.